# Filtering based on condition in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to filter a table based on some condition , 
I want to do the following :
if wire_on = 'true' i want to filter by both CUSTOMER_PARTITION_DT and country condition otherwise just CUSTOMER_PARTITION_DT .
Below is the statement I am using in my pig script :

```
B = FILTER A by ((wire_on=='true')?(dt=='$CUSTOMER_PARTITION_DT' AND NOT( country == 'RU' OR country == 'BG' OR country == 'LV' OR country == 'LT' OR country== 'EE' OR country=='KG' OR country=='KZ' OR country == 'MD' OR country == 'TJ' OR country =='TM' OR country == 'UA' OR country == 'GE' OR country == 'BY' OR country == 'UZ' OR country =='AM' OR country == 'AZ')):(dt=='$CUSTOMER_PARTITION_DT'));
```

I am getting a NoViableAltException

Can someone help me with this

```
EDIT :

Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: NoViableAltException(6@[])
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:199)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1735)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1443)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:387)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:412)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:398)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:171)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:624)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: NoViableAltException(6@[])
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.expr(AstValidator.java:8637)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.expr(AstValidator.java:9115)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.bin_expr(AstValidator.java:10531)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.projectable_expr(AstValidator.java:9790)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.var_expr(AstValidator.java:9582)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.expr(AstValidator.java:8985)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.cond(AstValidator.java:7820)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.filter_clause(AstValidator.java:7328)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.op_clause(AstValidator.java:1683)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.general_statement(AstValidator.java:1035)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.statement(AstValidator.java:499)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.AstValidator.query(AstValidator.java:373)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.validateAst(QueryParserDriver.java:258)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:186)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: Full stacktrace is helpful. Maybe look at e.g. [Pig - use ternary condition to filter based on different condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909024/pig-use-ternary-condition-to-filter-based-on-different-condition), or [Using Pig conditional operator to implement or?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378675/using-pig-conditional-operator-to-implement-or) ... Thanks. PS: Since 0.12.0 Pig has an IN operator ;-) that might be cool to replace the OR chain ...and help clear the field to spot the error ...

Comment: i  have added the full stack trace as requested

Comment: The caused by part is cut ... but does not the following look clearer, does the same (untested as I have no PIG access now) `B = FILTER A by dt=='$CUSTOMER_PARTITION_DT' AND NOT ( wire_on=='true' ? country IN('AM', 'AZ', 'BG', 'BY', 'EE', 'GE', 'KG', 'KZ', 'LT', 'LV', 'MD', 'RU', 'TJ', 'TM', 'UA', 'UZ'): false );` and maybe helps PIG knowledgeable persons to spot that syntax / parser error (this seems to be), as no viable alternative reads like a syntax error of the statement spot by the AST validator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can debug the situation, I hope this answers your question by enabling you to find the problem yourself, otherwise I can update it based on your additional input:

1. Ensure that the code does not give an error if you comment out the filter line
2. Make the most trivial filter and try to run it

### If a trivial run is succesfull

Gradually make it more complicated, if you found the exact spot where adding complication makes it fail, (possibly in this question)

### If a trivial run is unsuccesfull

If even the most trivial case fails, make sure to create a reproducible example and examine that (possibly in this question)

Comment: In addition to this, you could also try whether it helps to rewrite the logic condition in a way that doesn't need the if-then-else statement. Something like DTcond AND ((wirecond AND NOT countrycond) OR (NOT wirecond)), or even use two consecutive filter statements (or 3 and a union)